# unittest.main() to run all test modules in a package

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have several test modules saved in \tests. I then load them in the main class prior to running the main program by specifying

```
from tests.ClassTests1 import *
from tests.ClassTests2 import *
...

unittest.main()
```

Is there any way to instruct unittest.main() to run all the files in \tests without going through endless repetition of importing them as above? E.g. I tried `from tests import *` and it does not work.

EDIT: I am after the programmatic discovery not the discover via the command-line.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks goes to John Gordon for his links. Here's what made it work for me:

```
from tests.ClassTests1 import *

# Run test cases first
suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests', pattern='ClassTests*.py')
result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

However, I still need to import at least one test module, and I'm not sure if I'm doing this right as it discovers the entire test hierarchy of `tests`.

Comment: There's no need to import the test module, a simple `import unittest` worked for me.

Comment: _Captain Obvious_ had seen this answer and kindly suggests that you also might want to import `sys` and add `sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())` as the last line for this to propagate failures

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html, section 25.3.3. Test Discovery:

> Unittest supports simple test discovery. In order to be compatible with test discovery, all of the test files must be modules or packages importable from the top-level directory of the project (this means that their filenames must be valid identifiers).
>
> Test discovery is implemented in TestLoader.discover(), but can also be used from the command line. The basic command-line usage is:
>
> `cd project_directory`
>
> `python -m unittest discover`

Comment: I have updated the question now to make it clearer a bit: I am after the programmatic discovery not the discover via command-line. What would be syntax for TestLoader.discover() inside a python module. Thanks!

Comment: `TestLoader.discover()` returns a `TestSuite` object containing all the tests that were discovered.  Execute the `.run()` method of the returned TestSuite object to run those tests.  (This is all explained fairly well in the link I posted in my answer.  Did you read it thoroughly?)

Comment: Thanks! It is a massive read and I'm new to python. So i managed to make it discover the tests, however, what I cannot figure out is how to deal with imports. Right now for it to run I need to specify at least one test module explicitly as import, e.g. `from tests.ClassTests1 import *`. Which is counter-intuitive as I'm actually discovering the entire tests suite. But without this import it does not compile. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help!